# kaminari pagination shows previous results at next page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, kaminari

Pagination for Google map or many apis have "next_token" not to show previous contents. However Kaminari shows previous contents if new contents are created and then go to next page. 
Please let me know how to generate like next_token with Kaminari or other gem.

Answer (score 0):

This might be because immediately after addition of new data the page definition is changed. What i mean is with every call all the results are divided into pages while doing this if new data takes up your present page. The next button might actually point to your previous data.